# Clear current interval from outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to set up a timer that starts on page load and runs every second, I have that part working.

When you have less than 5 minutes left a modal pops up telling you your session will expire in 5 minutes, I have this part working as well.

The part I am struggling with is that when you close the modal it is meant to stop the interval and then restart it. I am able to get it to either start/stop the interval but I can't get it to do both.

I am new to JS so any help is appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  restartCountdown();
  timeRemaining = 1 * 60 * 1000;

  function restartCountdown() {
    countdown = setInterval(function() {
      startCountdown();
      timeRemaining -= 1000;
    }, 1000);
  }

  $(".closeModal").on('click', function() {
    //clear countdown
    clearInterval(countdown);
    //restart countdown
    restartCountdown();
  });
});

function startCountdown() {
  const qtyInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="qty"]');
  const minutesToUpdate = document.getElementById('minsLeft');

  //let countdown = setInterval( () =>{            
  let min = Math.floor(timeRemaining / (60 * 1000));
  let sec = Math.floor((timeRemaining - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);

  console.log("min left: " + min + " seconds left: " + sec);

  qtyInputs.forEach(function(qtyInput) {
    qtyInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      console.log("interval has been cleared");
    });
  });

  if (min <= 5 && sec <= 0) {
    $('#sessionModal').modal('show');
  }

  if (timeRemaining == 0) {
    //clearInterval(countdown);
    window.location.reload();
    console.log("page will refresh");
    $('#sessionModal').modal('hide');
  }

  if (sec < 10) {
    secondsLeft = "0" + sec;
  } else {
    secondsLeft = sec;
  }

  minutesToUpdate.innerHTML = '0' + min + ':' + secondsLeft + '';
  //}, 1000)
}
```

Comment: What are you struggling with, specifically? From what I see of your code, it seems to me that you should set the value of `timeRemaining` when you call `restartCoundown` to its initial value `timeRemaining = 1 * 60 * 1000;`.

Comment: @mgarcia Thanks very much, that has worked. Can I ask why this would need to be done? is it because after clicking to close the modal, it doesn't pass over the timeRemaining var?

Comment: I posted a more detailed answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @mgarcia I understand now, thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you are not setting the value of `timeRemaining` to its initial value when you call `restartCountdown`.

When you click on the close modal button, you are clearing the interval of `countdown` and calling `restartCountdown` so that your interval starts again.

But you are tracking the remaining time in `timeRemaining` (which starts at 1 * 60 * 1000). This variable is decreased by 1000 ms every time the interval callback is called.

So, when you want to restart your countdown you have to set it again to its initial value so that the remaining time starts from its top value.